# How can I create a jquery element with a taglib prefix?

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, taglib

Is it possible to create a jquery element with a spring taglib prefix?

In my jsp I have my taglib

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
```

And I would like to do:

```
             $('<form:input/>', {type: "hidden", prefix: "form", path: "critList["+j+"].attrib", value : splitted[0]  }).appendTo("form[name='cisManagerForm']");
             $('<form:input/>', {type: "hidden", prefix: "form", path: "critList["+j+"].operator", value : splitted[1]  }).appendTo("form[name='cisManagerForm']");
             $('<form:input/>', {type: "hidden", prefix: "form", path: "critList["+j+"].value1", value : splitted[2]  }).appendTo("form[name='cisManagerForm']");
```

but I get an error with the "form:input" notation when I try to deploy the page in Apache. And if I do not added the "form" prefix to the input, the input values do not seem to be sent to my server code on java/spring.

Any suggestions?

---

By the way, adding a little bit more context to the question. My goal is to be able to populate a AutoPopulatingList on the server side, based on data transformations I've did with javascript on the client side (at the same time I'm sending some other data to server with the same POST).

Comment: Your JSP code should be converted to regular HTML on the server-side, then sent to the browser. You'll need to figure out what the element created by your JSP tag looks like in HTML, and re-create an element of that type in JavaScript.

Comment: The generated html does not have the "form" taglib prefix. So I'm now wondering if it is actually possible to generate code with jquery with that prefix...

Comment: No, it's not - my point was that you *don't need to*. That prefix is to signify that it's a JSP tag, so that it's processed on the server-side and returns the corresponding HTML to the browser.

Comment: I guess for this question (of the taglib prefix) we can then say that it is not possible. Ill try to formulate a bit better another one specifically on how to get dynamically  generated jquery elements into my form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using javascript to create spring tag markup for your form elements would make your html invalid.

If I understood correctly, you'd like to build your form dynamically on the client side using javascript and would like to bind the new elements created server side.. If so, there's no easy answer other than iterating through the items in the request parameters... e.g.

```
Enumeration en = request.getParameterNames();
ArrayList params = new ArrayList();
while (en.hasMoreElements())
{
    String name = (String)en.nextElement();
    NameValuePair pair = new NameValuePair(name, request.getParameter(name));
    params.add(pair);
}
```

Comment: Actually what I want is a bit different from that =D I want to build my form dynamically with javascript/jquery, but then "glue" the data filled in the form (modified by some logic with javascript) into a spring AutoPopulatingList... I think Ill create a more specific question, and then Ill add the link here in the comment